# Does anyone know a public open GPS datasets with labeled visited places (POI) that we can use in research projects?

Tags: data-request, geospatial

We are working on outdoor activity recognition and we need to test our approaches using a labeled dataset containing pedestrians' mobility traces.

After some research, I have found [GeoLife](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/downloads/b16d359d-d164-469e-9fd4-daa38f2b2e13/default.aspx) dataset (can be found here : [crawdad.org/keyword-GPS.html](http://crawdad.org/keyword-GPS.html)). Sadly, this dataset doesn't contain labels of visited places. Any suggestions of labeled mobility traces (e.g. home, work) ?

Comment: One MIT project crowdsourced GPS movements for research. I can't find it right now, but this is the data that led to a conclusion that GPS traces alone can uniquely identify users (a privacy issue).

Answer (score 3):

The open source version of Google's Street View sounds like it has the data you desire, although it may not be in the same context; people walking down the street taking pictures of streets, doesn't sound the same as people involved in outdoor activities (although technically it is an activity)...I'll let you decide.
Open Street View:
http://openstreetview.org/

Comment: Thank you for your answer, indeed, Openstreetview is a good project, however, their databases don't include the users' GPS traces  when taking photos, i mean the photos are Geo-tagged but not the user's trip. I need both of them ^^.

Answer (score 3):

Mapillary, which a new attempt at an open source version of Google Street View, and which is track-based?

http://www.mapillary.com/map/im/n6Qyff8D-AmzR5bg_Bae2A/photo